# How can I turn off iCloud storage space warning notifications?

Tags: macos, icloud, notifications

On my Mac I've been getting many pop-up and email notifications about my meager iCloud storage space.

I only really use iCloud with iOS and chose to sign in to my same account on my Mac.

There's no chance that I'll upgrade so how can I turn off these Mac warnings that iCloud storage is close to full?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your options are limited here.

1. Turn off iCloud Backup altogether.
   Some info on how to selectively or collectively switch off iCloud is here: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2613?locale=en_GB&viewlocale=en_US
2. Back up less, e.g. by deciding not to back up your camera roll. I carefully manage what gets backed up and what not (and also which app gets mobile internet access).
   To see which apps on your phone are taking up the most space follow these steps:

   - Open the settings app
   - Tap iCoud
   - Scroll down to Storage & Backup and open it
   - Tap Manage Storage
   - Select your iPhone
3. If you're on Windows 10 (unlikely in this forum...), type in the Windows 10 search box *Settings* and select "Settings Trusted Windows Store App"

   - Click "System"
   - Click "Notifications & Actions"
   - Scroll down to "Show Notifications from these apps"
   - find "iCloud" and turn it off
     This works for other offending app notifications

Answer (score 5):

Notifications pop-up when your iCloud is configured for back-up data. You can disable this and have your iPod, iPad or iPhone backed up to your computer instead.

[Here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12520?locale=en_US):

> iCloud automatically backs up your iOS device information daily over
> Wi-Fi when your device is turned on, locked, and connected to a power
> source.
>
> **Back up automatically**
>
> On your iOS 9 or iOS 8 device: Go to Settings >
> iCloud > Backup, then turn on iCloud Backup.
>
> On your iOS 7 device: Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup, then
> turn on iCloud Backup.
>
> **Back up manually**
>
> On your iOS 9 or iOS 8 device: Go to Settings >
> iCloud > Backup, then tap Back Up Now.
>
> On your iOS 7 device: Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup, then
> tap Back Up Now.
>
> For information about messages that may appear while backing up, see
> the Apple Support article Get help backing up your device in iCloud.
>
> Important:   If you don’t back up your iOS device to iCloud for 180
> days or more, Apple reserves the right to delete your device’s iCloud
> backups. For information, see iCloud Terms and Conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing "Your iCloud storage is full." in macOS Notes:

[image]

I finally found the solution. You have too much local media storage in `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/`.

If you accidentally paste a large file (e.g. a 5.68 GB video file) from the clipboard into an Apple note, in addition to it having great trouble trying to literally paste it into the note, Notes.app manages to store that file in the Notes local storage folder. If you have less than that in your iCloud storage quota, this pop-up happens.

To fix:

1. Quit Notes.app
2. In `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/` go to `Accounts` folder, then the one that pertains to your iCloud, then `media` folder. Find the offending folder containing the large file you just tried to paste, and delete it.
3. Open Notes.app and the nagging pop-ups will disappear.

Definitely an Apple bug. I already reported it to Apple a long time ago, and never heard back.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to your system preferences for ICloud and unclick the square next to notes. After that, click it back on. The notifications will stop.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  This doesn't really answer the question.  How will doing what you indicate cause the notifications to stop?  The OP didn't mention Notes so why would checking this box have anything to do with it.  Please see [answer] for tips on how to provide a good answer.

Comment: @fsb I'd say Notes is one of the worst offenders wrt "many pop-up... notifications about my meager iCloud storage space". The OP doesn't mention backups *qua* backups explicitly. Now that iCloud is full, I get these notifications [that boil down to adverts] in Notes & Photos every time I open the danged things, sometimes multiple times in one session. So *very* germane to the OP, imo.

Comment: @ruffin The OP is asking how to get iCloud space notifications to stop.  This answer will not stop the notifications from appearing nor does it indicate why checking and unchecking the box for Notes would prevent the notifications. If you think this answer is correct, feel free to [edit] it to improve upon the answer.

Comment: I followed these directions and all my notes locally on my mac disappeared. Highly recommend NOT following this advice.